# I need to sort Questions and Answers by Thumbs Up minus Thumbs down

Tags: magento2, third-party-module

I need to sort questions and answers in this module:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dq0LzO6yVt_FHVvavGL74U1d1WEDzlrC

according to Thumbs UP - (minus) Thumbs Down key, so when question/answer has 5 ups and 3 downs, it will be taken as 2, so 3 ups and 0 ups will be first (3-0=3 is higher than 2).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

require(['jquery'],function($){ 

jQuery(".plus").click(function()
        {
            var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val());

            if (!currentVal || currentVal=="" || currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;

            jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
        });

jQuery(".minus").click(function()
    { 
         var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).closest('.quantity').find('.qty').val());
        if (currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
        if (currentVal > 1)
        {
            jQuery(this).closest('.quantity').find('.qty').val(currentVal - 1);
        }
});


});
</script>
```

Please Try This. Please Change variables according your need.